# Unable to resolve module @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/native could not be found within the project or in these directories:

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

the error:
Error: Unable to resolve module @react-navigation/native from D:\react-native-practice\app1\App.tsx: @react-navigation/native could not be found within the project or in these directories:

[image: error]

my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import Button from './components/Button';
import InputFeild from './components/InputFeild';

const App = () =>{
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.emptyProfile}>
                <Ionicons name="person-outline"  size={50}/>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputFeilds}>
                <InputFeild name="user_name" banner="at-outline" secutiry={false}/>
                <InputFeild name="password" banner="lock-closed-outline" secutiry={true}/>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.actions}>
                <Button buttonIcon="log-in-outline" text="Sign In" buttonActivated={true}/>
                <Button buttonIcon="person-add-outline" text="New user? Sign Up" buttonActivated={false} 
                    onPress={() => {
                        
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yeah, I guess... I figure out how to solve it with one of my friends....

Answer (score 1):

install these package in your Project and restart the project `npm install @react-navigation/native` 
View these documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Comment: already installed